# Which panel unit root tests should I use? Panel of 7 countries and 7 years

Tags: panel-data, stata, unit-root

I have a balanced data of 7 years and looking into 7 countries. There are many panel unit root tests to be used. I am looking at using the Fisher-type and IPS tests but there are more than that and I am not sure which test to choose as I have a sample of small N and small T.

I am a beginner at unit root tests and I will be using Stata for this test.

Comment: So you have 7 yearly observations (or 28 quarterly, or 84 monthly, or...)?

Comment: @RichardHardy  Hi Richard, nature of the data is a balanced panel of non-overlapping 5-year data of 7 countries from 1980 to 2010. I have ran the hausman test and confirmed that fixed effects is appropriate. However I am not sure what unit root tests I should run

Comment: If it's yearly observations I am inclined to say: none - too little data for results that are remotely reliable

Comment: @ChristophHanck they are a panel of non-overlapping 5 year data, what other validity tests could I perform then?